# Rich Text Default Value?

Tags: ms-access-2016

It would be really nice to have a rich text field that could also have a rich text default value. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

As is: A. B. C. D.

My dream:

A.

B.

C.

D.

Comment: Well, it is HTML, so set the _DefaultValue_ to to an _HTML string_ that will make your dream come true.

Comment: That doesn't work. I set it to: ="<div><strong>A.</strong></div>"    ...The field is blank. The field is rich text format also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work.

```
"<div><strong>A.</strong></div>" ->
```

[image: Table]

And in a form:

[image: Form]

Comment: Can you do this to a form field? This is a table.

Comment: Yes. Added picture.

Comment: But in the form I do not want it as the html code, infact I want the normal text with the the html changes. in that format

Comment: @itiDi: Isn't that what shown in the last textbox labelled RTF?

Comment: @Gustav Oh sorry....skipped that. But what is that textbox? Coz I did not get how did it change. I have issue somewhat related to that only, buy using MUI rich text editor, where I don't see my default value on that text editor in Reactjs

Comment: @itiDi: That is a textbox having its property _TextFormat_ (second option on second tab: _Data_ on the properties' pane) set to: Rich Text.

Comment: @Gustav okay..okay